# Laravel project deployed to shared hosting returns HTTP error 500

Tags: laravel

I have deployed laravel project to shared hosting but it returns HTTP error 500.

I will shortly describe to you all steps I have done and if there is mistake pls help :)

So here we go...
-I have run **composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev**
-I have run **PHP artisan config:cache** **then PHP artisan config:clear**
-After that I have run **npm run prod** and *exported refreshed database with seeded admin acc*

-In cPanel I have created database (from .env) and a username and his password (and added all that to .env)
Also, I have connected that admin acc and database successfully :)
-Then I have imported refreshed database in DB that I have just made on cPanel

-All files from the public folder I have uploaded to public_html
-And all folders and files (except public) I have created a new folder in the root and uploaded the rest of the project there
-After that, I went back to public_html/index.php and changed the path of 2 lines:
1. require *DIR*
2. $app = require_once

So instead of

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php
```

I have put

```
require __DIR__.'/../folder_name_where_rest_of_app_is/vendor/autoload.php
```

And, same is done for $app line ...

Saved latest changes and then I have tried to refresh the site and it just throws HTTP Error 500

PS: Also I have added these lines

```
APP_ENV=production


APP_DEBUG=false
```

And on APP_URL is the copied URL from the browser...

If anywhere you can see any mistakes please tell me :)

Comment: Is there anything in the logs? *storage/logs/*

Comment: @None Don't see anything :3 Just old data when I was creating website

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities.

To debug, limit access with something like HTTP basic auth or IP access control and turn on `APP_DEBUG`.

Check the log files in *storage/logs/* and the web server logs.

Make sure the environment has an encryption key set. If not run:

`php artisan key:generate`